# Android Studio Theme rendering problems

Tags: java, android-layout

This is the image with the problem
http://imgur.com/uUd3its

I have tried solutions in other posts and I still get this rendering Problems with all themes in Android Studio.

Comment: please add your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Its quite popular issue with novice.

There are many possibilities of failure to not render UI layouts.

First and foremost solution is to resolve by going with Android Studio's default recommendations.

If it still fails to resolve then need to go for manual solution.

(1.) Incompatible API support Issue :
        -- Ref to same snapshot, there is little droid icon with number 23(in your case). This represents the latest supporting API. You may select lower API no than current number (i.e. 22, 21, etc.) and then let system render the UI layout. If its success then you may again update with latest API number (i.e. 23)

2.) There could be possibilities of inappropriate reference to related activity java file/other resources.

If you submit all code then one would be able to give specific solution to your problem.

Cheers!

**

- UPDATE 1 :

**
If require try these solutions too.
          -> As this is not a syntax error; means you can run the app. After launched app on simulator/handset; come back to design xml file and check for rendering issue. It has worked many times to me.

Hope this update solution would help you out. If yes please accept the answer to help others and if not then let me know.

If you have found any other working solution then please update your answer to help others out.

Cheers!